# Android - Apply a 9 Patch in Code

Tags: java, android, nine-patch

How may I apply a 9 patch to an Android TextView IN CODE?

Why, you may ask? Because I need to dynamically set the number of controls.

I'm try to do something similar and its not working:

(my 9 patch "notif_bubble_white.9.png" in code is R.drawable.notif_bubble_white)

```
  tv = new TextView(this); 
  tv.setText("Test Message"); 
  tv.setLayoutParams(lpL); 
  tv.setPadding(0, 0, paddingValue, 0); 
  CustomFonts.ApplyFont_Custom1(tv, context); 
  tv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.notif_bubble_white); 
  // tv.setTextColor(TxtColFromCl); 
  layout.addView(tv);
```

where lpL was defined as:

```
  LinearLayout.LayoutParams lpL = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

Comment: "How may I apply a 9 patch to an Android TextView IN CODE?" There's his question, lol

Answer (score 0):

You can either just create the controls all at once and hide them with `control.setVisibility(View.GONE)` until needed, or, if the number of controls are unknown, you can inflate a layout file, like described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2542897/inflate-vs-findviewbyid).

Code copied from referenced question (credits to Cedric, or Pentium10, idk, and assuming control is a button):

button.xml:

```
<Button
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/button01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Inflating the button:

```
button = (Button) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.button, null);
```

Comment: In the XML code you can add the 9patch background, and the inflater will always inflate the 9patch correctly